# How to compile OpenCL kernel into binary for an AMD GPU that I don't physically have?

Tags: opencl, amd-gpu

I have found some references on AMD forums that it is possible to do offline compilation for a target GPU not physically installed in the system that does the compilation. But I can't find a way to do this.

In other words, how can I create a binary for 6900XT without buying this card?

P. S. Both the host and the target operating systems are Windows 10.

Comment: You may want to include the (operating) systems you are trying to target in the question.

Comment: @pmdj: done, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I've had luck using RGA for OpenCL  (ROC-m). https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/radeon_gpu_analyzer/releases but I don't know all the AMD microarchs.

Comment: @Tim: I've looked at it; it doesn't list any architectures past Radeon VII. No RDNA.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is use the AMD's `CL_CONTEXT_OFFLINE_DEVICES_AMD` extension which lets you creat OCL context and invoke OCL functions for any specified GPU model as if the card was actually present in your system.
Here's the Github repo (written by someone else many years ago) that does it: https://github.com/anyc/ocl-ke/blob/master/ocl-ke.c